# Dynamically changing CC field from adjacent cell details

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have piece of VBA code in an excel workbook that is currently working, but when attempting to add another capability to the VBA, the code returns an error.

**Background:** On a button click, if Column U contains a value of "Y" an email will be sent with the name of the client (Column W) in the email subject & body. I would like to add in the email address of the account manager (Column V) so that it changes for each email sent.

I understand that Rng is on a procedure-level scope and that it's only visible to notify() so am aiming to define it beforehand and then "calling" it to mymacro(). I've tried to add an additional Sub, but that didn't work.

Have tried using 2 if statements (as below) but don't think this is on the right track either.

I think the issue might be with me incorrectly defining scopes? Or perhaps incorrectly defining "EmailAddr"?

```
    Sub notify()
      Dim Rng As Range
      Dim EmailAddr As String

       For Each Rng In Range("U3:W200")
         If (Rng.Value = "Y") Then
           mymacro theValue:=Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
         End If
   
         If (Rng.Value = "Y") Then
           mymacro EmailAddr = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
         End If
   
      Next Rng
    End Sub
```

---

```
    Private Sub mymacro(theValue As String, EmailAddr As String)
      Dim xOutApp As Object
      Dim xOutMail As Object
      Dim xMailBody As String

      Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
      xMailBody = "Hi All" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "This alert has been created via the Compliance Register." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Please review the insurance(s) for " & theValue & " that are due to expire in the next 30 days." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

      With xOutMail
           .To = "generalmanager@gmail.com;financemanager@gmail.com"
           .CC = EmailAddr
           .BCC = ""
           .Subject = "Insurance(s) for " & theValue & " are expiring soon."
           .Body = xMailBody
           .Display   'or use .Send
     End With

     On Error GoTo 0
     Set xOutMail = Nothing
     Set xOutApp = Nothing
   End Sub
```

The code works perfectly if all "EmailAddr" components are removed from both notify() and mymacro() - but, of course, leaves the CC component empty. I'm still a novice at intuitively changing code to suit my needs, so a point in the right direction would be great.

Let me know if I can clarify anything in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop; change

```
If (Rng.Value = "Y") Then
    mymacro theValue:=Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
End If

If (Rng.Value = "Y") Then
   mymacro EmailAddr = Rng.Offset(0, 1)
End If
```

to

```
If (Rng.Value = "Y") Then
   mymacro theValue:=Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value, EmailAddr:=Rng.Offset(0, 1)
End If
```

and remove the `Dim EmailAddr As String`, since it is a named argument of `mymacro`, not a local variable.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen! I did try something similar before when I was playing around with the code but had added mymacro again in from of EmailAddr (also without a comma) - my syntax clearly needs to be improved.